# Software for USB webcam?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, usb, webcam

I'm looking for simple Windows 7-compatible free software to capture and output images from my bog-standard USB webcam.

If there is a built-in solution I'd be grateful.

I know I can use the *Import* function from **Windows Live Photo Gallery**, but it's tedious to get there - maybe I can access it directly using a command-line switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is Dorgem, it should work on Windows 7 too, works nicely on 64bit Vista and many other Windows versions I've tried it on. Dorgem can be downloaded here http://dorgem.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Dorgem almost does it for me. However it's incredible hard to use and is of, being abandonware, completely unsupported.

Comment: Yeah, development has stopped, but fortunately it just works and it actually isn't that hard to use once you read the howto.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but if it will run under Windows 7, will the Windows XP [Timershot](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) power toy serve your needs?

> **Webcam Timershot**
>
> This PowerToy lets you take pictures at specified time intervals from a Webcam connected to your computer and save them to a location that you designate.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried the Timershot powertoy.

It won't play nicely with Windows 7 - even with all the relevant compatibility settings it just won't start.

Comment: Well, bummer. At least it's ruled out of the potential candidates.

More importantly though, is that the functionality you're looking for?